# html form-submit doesnt show result from javascript permanently in element

Tags: javascript, html, css

im having the issue, that my html website seems to always refresh automatically twice after i submitted a form. 
I just see my - correct - result from the function behind the Submit for less than a second before it disappers.
I write the result into an tabledata element with document.getElementById("tabledata").innerHTML = result;

The code works fine, the result just doesn't remain in the tabledata element - but i want it to.

```
        <td id="TDcontent200px">
        <form name="formularSpiel" onSubmit="spielen()">
        <input type="radio" name="radioGruppe" value="Schere" checked="checked">Schere<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioGruppe" value="Stein">Stein<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioGruppe" value="Papier">Papier<br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </td>

function spielen()
{
    var meineWahl = getAuswahl();
    var gegnerWahl = waehleGegner();
    var ergebnis = vergleiche(meineWahl, gegnerWahl);
    document.getElementById("TDergebnis").innerHTML = ergebnis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you put

return false;

after that document.getElementById... line?

Comment: I did this, nothing changed.

Comment: oh... you are not using jQuery event handler.
Try this then

function spielen(e)
{
    var meineWahl = getAuswahl();
    var gegnerWahl = waehleGegner();
    var ergebnis = vergleiche(meineWahl, gegnerWahl);
    document.getElementById("TDergebnis").innerHTML = ergebnis;
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

Comment: I use simple javascript, i dont use jQuery. Also I am not familiar with event handlers.

Comment: understood... :)
then I think you will need 'e.preventDefault();' before 'return false;'

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem. @tom
I think I messed something up with the form and its use.
I deleted the "onsubmit" attribute and changed the input type from "submit" to "button" and added an "onclick" event on the button:

```
            <form name="formularSpiel">
        <input type="radio" name="radioGruppe" value="Schere"  checked="checked">Schere<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioGruppe" value="Stein">Stein<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioGruppe" value="Papier">Papier<br><br>
        <input **type="button"** value="submit" **onclick="spielen()"**>
        </form>
```

Problem solved, thx @tom